# Android is not displaying App Chooser dialog

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to implement an application that invokes the SMS client application. When the user selects "send SMS" he should be prompted to pick an app to send the sms. This is what I'm doing:

```
    private void sendSms(String number) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:"
                + number));
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources()
                .getString(R.string.app_chooser_title));

        startActivity(chooser);

    }
```

but no chooser is displayed, it opens the default SMS client instantly.
What am I doing wrong?

Marcus

Comment: Do you have more than one app for sms's?

Comment: I'm using the emulator, so probably not

Comment: That's why don't see the choose dialog. Because there is only one app.

Comment: I thought it was always displayed, regardless of how many apps. But okay, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 1 app the popup don't appear!

To start launch the sms activity all you need is this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
```

You can add extras to populate your own message and such like this

```
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", x);
```

then just startActivity with the intent.

```
startActivity(sendIntent);
```